# Embed revision number in executable binary

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I want to embed a git revision marker in my binary, but the linker appears to strip it away.

Makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS += -DREV=$(shell git describe)
```

file.c:

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
const char rev[]="rev[" xstr(REV) "]";
```

The marker is present in file.o:

```
$ strings file.o | grep rev
rev[v1.0.1-5-ga45db7f-dirty]
GCC: (15:7-2018-q2-6) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
```

But missing from file.elf:

```
$ strings file.elf | grep rev
GCC: (15:7-2018-q2-6) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
GCC: (15:7-2018-q2-5) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
GNU C11 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907] -mthumb -march=armv6s-m -g -g -g -O2 -O2 -O2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-inline -fvisibility=hidden
GNU C11 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907] -mthumb -march=armv6s-m -g -g -g -O2 -O2 -O2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-inline -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden
GNU C11 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907] -mthumb -march=armv6s-m -mthumb -march=armv6s-m -g -O2 -fno-builtin
prev_tzenv
LoopForever
prev_tzenv
.debug_abbrev
```

Linker command line:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=c99 -O3 -Wall -ffunction-sections -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft  -Tst/stm32f0xx-32-6.ld -Wl,-Map=dtc_main.map -Wl,--gc-sections  -specs=nano.specs -o file.elf file.o startup_stm32f0xx.o system_stm32f0xx.ao syscalls.o
```

Comment: So it is optimized out because not being used in your program.

Comment: Yes. I want to prevent this optimization. I could add some code that would twiddle some of these bytes, but I wonder if there's a way to tell the linker directly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Not sure if it will help... but you can try to place it into some separate section and then `keep` it.

Comment: Your compiler has some pragma which turns off optimization for just a part of the code. Or else make the array volatile.

Comment: @Fredrik Looks like the compiler is not optimizing it, but the linker is. Not sure compiler flags/pragmas will help with that.

Comment: @Eugene You’re right, then maybe volatile will work?

Comment: Just tried with volatile. Same result.

Comment: After --gc-sections try -Wl,--gc-keep-exported This should prevent removal of global symbols. In your case that would be 'rev'

Comment: Perhaps initialising as `extern` would prevent the linker removing the variable, and make the string available to all compilation units.

Comment: @LegendofPedro extern means it exists somewhere else, so if you make it extern there will be no variable to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You could either compile file with `rev` with `-fno-data-sections` or simply add a dummy use of it somewhere:

```
volatile int x = 0;
if (x)
  memcpy(NULL, rev, 1);
```